# Porque obtengo este resultado usando Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Estoy aprendiendo Redux y tengo una duda cuando aplico en este sencillo ejemplo:

```
const redux = require('redux');

const counterReducer = (state = { counter: 0 }, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'increment') {
    return {
      counter: state.counter + 1,
    };
  }

  if (action.type === 'decrement') {
    return {
      counter: state.counter - 1,
    };
  }

  return state;
};

const store = redux.createStore(counterReducer);

const counterSubscriber = () => {
  const latestState = store.getState();
  console.log(latestState);
};

store.subscribe(counterSubscriber);

store.dispatch({ type: 'increment' });
store.dispatch({ type: 'decrement' });
```

Obtengo como resultado :

```
{ counter: 1 }
{ counter: 0 }
```

Pero no debería obtener :

```
{ counter: 1 }
{ counter: -1 }
```

Porque el state inicia en 0 `state = { counter: 0 }` . Entonces al llamar a `increment` suma  1 y en `decrement` le resta 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los métodos `dispatch` se comportan como cualquier otra función en **JavaScript**, se ejecutan en secuencia.

Dicho esto y siguiendo la secuencia del código del OP, primero se ejecuta:

```
//JS: invoca al metodo dispatch de store
//el action object especifica increment
store.dispatch({ type: 'increment' });
```

El estado inicial es `state = { counter: 0 }`:

```
//JS: invoca al metodo dispatch de store
//el action object especifica increment
//en este momento state = { counter: 0 }
//entonces, según el reducer increment: 0+1=1
store.dispatch({ type: 'increment' });
//JS: el valor del estado ya cambio
//paso de 0 a 1
//el store nos ayuda a persistir el cambio
```

Luego, el `store` nos ayuda a persistir los cambios de valores en el estado, entonces al momento de invocar a:

```
store.dispatch({ type: 'decrement' });
```

El estado es `state = { counter: 1 }`:

```
//state = { counter: 0 }
store.dispatch({ type: 'increment' }); //state = { counter: 1 }
//JS: invoca al metodo dispatch de store
//el action object especifica decrement
//en este momento state = { counter: 1 }
//entonces, según el reducer increment: 1-1=0
store.dispatch({ type: 'decrement' });//state = { counter: 0 }
```

---

Puede que también sea confuso el método `subscribe`, pues esta declarado antes de la invocación de los métodos `dispatch`:

```
const counterSubscriber = () => {
  const latestState = store.getState();
  console.log(latestState);
};

store.subscribe(counterSubscriber);
```

Solo hay que recordar que este método pide una función que sera invocada inmediatamente después de cada `dispatch`.

En este caso la función que se va a invocar después de cada dispatch es `counterSubscriber`, que es donde se esta monitoreando por consola los cambios de estado.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.